# how to delay text to speech code on textboxes visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make my visual basic code speak multiple text boxes with a delay of 30 seconds between each textbox, so far i have:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    End If
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
        Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox2.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox3.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox4.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox5.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox6.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox7.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox8.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox9.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
        TextBox10.Text = ioFile.ReadLine()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim SAPI
    SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
    SAPI.Speak(TextBox1.Text)




End Sub
```

End Class

Basically i have 10 text boxes that have 10 words in them (loaded form a txt file) and i have a txt to speech code saying the first textbox but i want that text to speech code linked to button 2 to say all the textboxes with a 30 second delay between each textbox, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: would a timer work?  and maybe an index variable?

Comment: how would i go about using a timer to make it play textbox2 30 seconds after playing textbox1?

Comment: Your question is the answer... set the TIMER for 30 SECONDS when you  play TEXTBOX1. then when the in the timer tick event play the next thing.  Use an index variable to track which box to play.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you probably want a multithreaded application. However if you don't a quick and dirty way of making it would would be:

```
system.threading.thread.sleep(30000)
```

But then the UI would lock up. So you really want this running on a different thread. A timer is the easiest way to implement this. Just have the timer.tick value set to 30,000. When button 2 is pressed have it create an array with all the textbox strings in. The have a global variable (integer). Each time the timer is ticked it speaks the text in the array at the ndex of the global variable, then increment the global variable!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If this answer is sufficient (or the other answer) please mark it as the answer and up vote it. Otherwise people like me will try and provide a better answer :p

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a BackgroundWorker() and an Enumerator built from the words in the TextBoxes:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim matches() As Control
            Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            For i As Integer = 1 To 10
                matches = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)
                If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
                    If i <= lines.Count Then
                        DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox).Text = lines(i - 1)
                    Else
                        DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox).Text = ""
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            Dim words As New List(Of String)
            Dim matches() As Control
            For i As Integer = 1 To 10
                matches = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)
                If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
                    Dim TB As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
                    If TB.Text.Trim <> "" Then
                        words.Add(TB.Text.Trim)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If words.Count > 0 Then
                BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(words.GetEnumerator)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
        Dim wordsEnum As IEnumerator(Of String) = DirectCast(e.Argument, IEnumerator(Of String))
        While wordsEnum.MoveNext
            SAPI.Speak(wordsEnum.Current)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        MessageBox.Show("Done!")
    End Sub

End Class
```